# A form is not submitted when the form is used as a title prop of TreeNode (andt design)

Tags: antd

In this code we use Button with Modal in TreeNode. There is the form in Modal and Ok Button is bound to form with using form ('myForm') attribute. But form is not submitted with button. It looks like submition doesn't work at all.
According to my investiagation it is related with Tree and TreeNode components.

The example of my code:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Modal, Button, Input, Tree } from "antd";

const { TreeNode } = Tree;

const renderForm = (handleSubmit, onSubmit, control) => (
  <form id="myForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Controller
      as={<Input placeholder="Type" />}
      control={control}
      name="title"
    />
  </form>
);

const Comp = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const handleOk = e => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = e => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const onSubmit = ({ title }) => {
    console.log(title);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={visible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        okButtonProps={{
          htmlType: "submit",
          form: "myForm"
        }}
      >
        {useMemo(() => renderForm(handleSubmit, onSubmit, control), [
          control,
          handleSubmit
        ])}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <Tree>
    <TreeNode key="ert" title={<Comp />} />
  </Tree>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```